# WooCommerce capture the times from a product timedate for filtering

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, woocommerce

I am working on creating a filter on a set of products.
These products are actually different classes that have their `start datetime` and `end datetime` (Custom fields).

I am trying to create a Time range filter (https://codepen.io/caseymhunt/pen/kertA), which will then show any products whose `start datetime` has a time within the range selected.

An example is, by default, I want to show all products that are between 8am and 8pm (regardless of the date, just the time).

The products have a custom field called class_startTime which can look like `2020-08-03 17:00`

I got my code working for filters with age group easily, I'm totally lost in what to do to get a range of 2 times (such as 8am and 8pm).

```
    <ul class="products">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'LIKE',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'age_group',
                    'value'   => $agefilter,
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'class_startTime',
                    'value'   => date("Y-m-d").' 17:00',
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'type' => 'DATETIME'
                ),
            ),
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order'         => 'ASC'
            );

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul>
```

I tried to just use the hours, but that didn't work at all.

Comment: Want to share that i found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679956/wordpress-meta-query-between-2-dates

Which is getting me closer to compare two dates, but no luck yet regarding comparing time.

Comment: If you want to find the product that has `2020-08-03 17:00`, regardless of the date - then what sense does it make to compare it to `date("Y-m-d").' 17:00'`? Unless today is the 3rd of August 2020, `Y-m-d` will of course _not_ be `2020-08-03` - so you will not find that product on any day prior to this date. You said yourself that you want this comparison _without_ the date - so why are you stuffing a _specific_ date value into there in the first place then?

Comment: Your code effectively runs an sql database query. You need to solve your problem in two steps: First, figure out the correct sql query for your problem - you can do this without any coding, just use a db client. Second, figure out how the write the php code correctly to execute that query.

Comment: @CBroe removing YMD breaks the query, trying to figure out how to search without it and just the time. 

thank you! im trying out different queries, i can see thats the direction other questions have used, will try this now.

If anyone happens to know how to do searches of just H i instead of YMD H i, please do share :)

Comment: @AndreasVogl i managed to find the type of sql query that will work 

DATEPART(hh,[dateColumn]) >= 8 AND DATEPART(hh,[dateColumn]) <= 20 
       
   

just sharing progress here :)